# Stylesheet for specific page overwritten by standard css

Tags: theming, 7

In my subtheme.info I have :

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

And in my template.php I have:

```
function subtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $path = current_path();

    if ($path == 'user/login') {
        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'subtheme') . "/css/login.css");
    }
}
```

But when I load the page, my `style.css` is declared after my `login.css`. So my styles in `login.css` are overwritten by `styles.css`. How can I make sure the `login.css` is declared after the `styles.css`?

Comment: Can't you just style what you need using `#user-login` ID or `.page-user-login` class in CSS? Simpler code, faster execution, easier caching...

Comment: The problem is that my login page is totally different from my other pages. So I need the bg-color of my body and such..

Comment: `.page-user-login` is (or at least should be) a class set on a `<body>` element - I still fail to see a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add weight to the CSS:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'subtheme') . "/css/login.css", array('weight' => 100));
```

See the [`drupal_add_css()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) API page for more info. The **group** option may also be relevant as this also affects the weight.

Also if the specificity of a rule in style.css overrules a rule in login.css it won't matter what order the CSS files are included.

Comment: The problem is that my login page is totally different from my other pages. So I need the bg-color of my body and such... This isn't possible with this solution.

Comment: @nielsv if the code in your question makes it possible, then changes suggested by Felix Eve simply cannot break this possibility. How could they?

Comment: @nielsv What makes you say that isn't possible with this solution? I can guarantee you it is.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I didn't now that the body tag had a class "page-user-login". I'm still in the very beginning of learning drupal. Your solution works perfect and accepted!